# Blazor EventCallback with Multiple Params - how to respond to event in parent host control

Tags: blazor, webassembly, .net-5

I have a blazor component with an EventCallBack parameter that utilized the new struct format allowing multiple arguments

```
[Parameter] public EventCallback<(EmployeeShiftDay, DateTime, DateTime)> NewDayScrolledIntoView { get; set; }
```

eventcallback is invoked in child normally as such

```
await NewDayScrolledIntoView.InvokeAsync(p1, p2, p3);
```

In my host page I have the corresponding method to handle the invoke

```
private void NewDayInView(EmployeeShiftDay dayInView, DateTime weekStart, DateTime weekEnd)
{
   ...
}
```

How do I add the markup for this EventCallBack in the host component - I need of course 3 params not just one

```
<ShiftCardScroller NewDayScrolledIntoView="@((args) => NewDayInView(args))" ></ShiftCardScroller>
```

Comment: temporary solution is to reference the component in the parent host with @ref and access public properties in the child but would prefer to send via EventCallBack args

Comment: You shouldn't do that like that. Now it's only a warning. In the future an error.

Comment: agreed a bad way to do it - have implemented like you and @Brian Parker suggested thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are invoking it deconstructed:

```
await NewDayScrolledIntoView.InvokeAsync((p1, p2, p3));
```

When the event is received deconstruct it then:

```
<ShiftCardScroller NewDayScrolledIntoView="@((args)=> NewDayInView(args.Item1,args.Item2,args.Item3))" />
```

Comment: Did the same, now I get this error in parent component: 
CS0119 'EventCallback' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: I am using the TUPEL syntax consistently, unlike OP, for declaration, invokation and handler, yet the component parameter gives the error:  CS0119 'EventCallback' is a type, which is not valid in the given context multiple times and also  CS0119 'int' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Using tuples did not work for me. @Khabir solution worked fine.

Answer (score 11):

You can use custom Args Type as below:

```
public class EventCallbackArgs
{
    public bool Confirm { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is a sample blazor code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="() => OnConfirmationChange(true)">
    Delete
</button>
```

On Delete button click, **OnConfirmationChange** is called, inside the code of OnConfirmationChange, you can prepare **EventCallbackArgs** and invoke **ConfirmationChanged**

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<EventCallbackArgs> ConfirmationChanged { get; set; }
public EventCallbackArgs args { get; set; }

protected async Task OnConfirmationChange(bool deleteCofirmed)
{
    ShowConfirmation = false;
    args = new EventCallbackArgs { Id = id, Name = name };
    args.Confirm = deleteCofirmed;
    await ConfirmationChanged.InvokeAsync(args);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For me @Brian Parker's solution did not work a slightly modification needed:

*(same)*

```cs
await NewDayScrolledIntoView.InvokeAsync((p1, p2, p3));
```

Tuple casting:

```html
<ShiftCardScroller NewDayScrolledIntoView="@((args)=> NewDayInView(((EmployeeShiftDay,DateTime,DateTime))args))" />
```

Method takes one argument. The type is consistent with the previously casted type:

```cs
private void NewDayInView((EmployeeShiftDay,DateTime,DateTime)args)
{
   ...
}
```

Sometimes restarting the Visual studio is needed to get rid of the unrelevant error messages.

Comment: Please explain your modification, how it works and for which cases it is needed and why.

Comment: Is it appropiate now or should I make it more verbose?

Comment: I think more verbose would be better, also using phrases like "because", "in order to" and "thereby", "otherwise"... Consider having a look at [answer].

Comment: sadly this does not workf for me as well. with .NET 6 and current VS version, it seems TUPELS dont work here ?! even simply getting the args param (and doing nothing with it) does not work on step 3, when assigning the handler to the child component in the parent markup. surprissingly, even with the red squiggly lines the project COMPILES AND RUNS but the component behaves faulty. gonna try using a custom type then...

Comment: this actually worked to solve the issue with CS0119 'EventCallback' is a type..  I needed to adapt to my own situation. Then it worked fine. thanks !

Answer (score -1):

you should pass only the name of the Method to the child componant

```
<ShiftCardScroller NewDayScrolledIntoView="@NewDayInView" ></ShiftCardScroller>
```

and in the child componant you could invoke the callback with the the parameters that you want

```
NewDayScrolledIntoView.invokeAsync(Param1,Param1,Param3)
```

Comment: Thanks for comment but that is not allowed - am already invoking as you mentioned but the host control wont accept "method group" as EventCallBack - its looking for 3 arguments

Comment: @Laurence73 apparently this is not possible check this link : https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23182

Comment: according to this later post it is! it just doesnt show how to add the component markup! frustrating https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23603

Comment: I can also just pass back a custom single object with 3 properties too...but defeats the purpose of multiple param ability