# Multiple parameters with EventCallback in Blazor without creating a class and pass it

Tags: blazor

One year go a created a project where i passed multiple parameters following the answers on this question: [Blazor EventCallback with Multiple Params - how to respond to event in parent host control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65184334/blazor-eventcallback-with-multiple-params-how-to-respond-to-event-in-parent-ho)

When i tried now in .net 6 is not working(it is working with creating a class and passing the parameters to the fiels there, but for me is not the clean solution).

**Parent component:**

```
<MultipleParamsComp OnHandle="@((args) => await HandleParams(((int, string))args))" />

<p>@BaseId</p>
<p>@BaseString</p>


@code {
    private int BaseId = 0;
    private string BaseString = string.Empty;


    private async Task HandleParams((int, string) args)
    {
        BaseId = args.Item1;
        BaseString = args.Item2;
    }
}
```

**Child Component:**

```
<h4>Child Component</h4>


<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(() => HandleMultipleParams(id))">
    Testing
</button>


@code {
    private int id = 0;
    private string Name = "something";

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<(int, string)> OnHandle { get; set; }

    private async Task HandleMultipleParams(int customerId)
    {
        customerId++;

        await OnHandle.InvokeAsync((customerId, Name));
    }
}
```

**Output**

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1001  Identifier expected BlazorTheory    E:\Programare\Blazor\BlazorTheory\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Theory_EventCallBack_Other_Examples_Passing_multiple_params_in_function_BaseComponent1_razor.g.cs  90  Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0119  'string' is a type, which is not valid in the given context BlazorTheory    E:\Programare\Blazor\BlazorTheory\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Theory_EventCallBack_Other_Examples_Passing_multiple_params_in_function_BaseComponent1_razor.g.cs  90  Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0119  'int' is a type, which is not valid in the given context    BlazorTheory    E:\Programare\Blazor\BlazorTheory\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Theory_EventCallBack_Other_Examples_Passing_multiple_params_in_function_BaseComponent1_razor.g.cs  90  Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0119  'EventCallback' is a type, which is not valid in the given context  BlazorTheory    E:\Programare\Blazor\BlazorTheory\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Theory_EventCallBack_Other_Examples_Passing_multiple_params_in_function_BaseComponent1_razor.g.cs  90  Active

---

Maybe i lack some theory of delegates or EventCallback and how they work behind the scene(any good documentation links helps).

Ty u.

Comment: Please be more specific when you say "not working" - are you getting compilation errors? runtime errors? no errors, but unexpected behaviour? What is happening?

Comment: Why are you passing a local field as a parameter to a local non static member? You could as well just directly use `id`. Also,  `int` is a value type, so passing is as an argument will copy it. `id` itself will never be modified, so `customerId++;` will always give 1.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at following question-
[Blazor EventCallback with Multiple Params - how to respond to event in parent host control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65184334/blazor-eventcallback-with-multiple-params-how-to-respond-to-event-in-parent-ho)

```
await NewDayScrolledIntoView.InvokeAsync((p1, p2, p3));

<ShiftCardScroller NewDayScrolledIntoView="@((args)=> NewDayInView(args.Item1,args.Item2,args.Item3))" />
```